# AppServerHost.exe taking all the CPU

Tags: office-web-apps, document-converter

As soon as I open a doucment using Office Web Apps, I have three process that starts to take all the CPU.

The three processes are `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\WebServices\ConversionService\bin\Converter\AppServerHost.exe`.

There's nothing particular in the ULS logs.

What can I do to troubleshot the issue ?

PS: Don't know if it can help, but it's a demo computer running on the same box a W2K8 R2 OS, with AD role, Sql 2K8R2, SP2010 server enterprise (all possible services started, except foundation search and lotus connector) and Office Web apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is the DC role on the same machine. Try this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scicoria/archive/2011/04/14/getting-office-web-apps-to-run-on-a-domain-controller-appserverhost-exe.aspx

Comment: thanks, I forgot to answer my question when I found the solution